# SOS debugger in VS 2010 for Silverlight 4, enable unmanaged debugging

Tags: silverlight, sos

if I issue .load SOS while debugging in VS 2010 I get
"SOS not available while Managed only debugging.  To load SOS, enable unmanaged debugging in your project properties."

I accept that I need to enable this in project settings...but....where is the option? I've checked everywhere, and similar questions seem to refer to an option that isn't there.. :-/

Screen shot of project settings page follows....
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you running VS 2010 Express?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf.aspx

> Note: The Visual Studio Express Editions, such as Visual C# Express,
>   do not support debugging of unmanaged code. This is supported only in
>   the full Visual Studio product.

### Update:

Silverlight itself does not support unmanaged code at all due to its strict security sandbox. That means the option to enable debugging it would not be available in a Silverlight project.

Comment: I'm running VS 2010 Professional, Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1

Comment: Thinking about your question again: Silverlight itself does not support unmanaged code at all due to its strict security sandbox. That means the option to enable debugging it would not be in a Silverlight project.

Comment: Ok so are we saying that I can't use the SOS debugger in Silverligt projects do you think?